# Районы и регионы

Tags: грамотная-речь

Я специально отслеживала: слово "регионы" в столь широком употреблении, как сейчас (в значении "районы"), пошло от Горбачева (равно, как и выражение "в этой связи"). Но насколько оно вообще литературно? Зачем говорить "регион", когда можно сказать "район"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По поводу "этой связи" - весьма сомневаюсь, что это конкретно от Горбачева. Но это отдельный разговор.

Вот насчет "региона" в значении "район"... А кто так употребляет? Регион - это регион, в общем случае - составляющее географического целого.
В масштабах государства - субъекты федерации, в областном - районы, В районном - наверное, территориальные образования сельских муниципальных образований (сельсоветы?).
Причем это не строгое административное понятие, грубо говоря то, что называется глубинкой.

А можно примеры использования, коли Вы уж отслеживали?

Comment: "В этой связи" именно широко стало употребляться именно с подачи Горбачева.

Comment: Ему активно приписывают, но я сомневаюсь.


>В этой связи мы должны делать следующее: 1) помогать бедным; 2) служить больным; 3) утешать печальных; 4) облегчать положение несчастных; 5) со всеми обходиться кротко, с любовью и назидательно; 6) примиряться с гневающимися; 7) прощать обиды и делать и делать добрые дела врагам. [митрополит Филарет (Дроздов). Пространный христианский Катихизис Православной кафолической восточной церкви (1823-1824)] [омонимия не снята] ←…→

(нацкорпус). По времени - разве что прапрапрабабушка Михалсергеича...

Answer (score 2):

Район - это административная единица, имеющая четкие границы. Регион - понятие более абстрактное. В значении "район" Горбачев вряд ли употреблял это слово. Скорее всего, он имел в виду именно регион.